# Windows 10 PING returns "No resources." - why?

Tags: windows, networking, dns, ping, network-interface

I often have this problem:

```
C:\Users\user> ping 8.8.8.8

Pinging 8.8.8.8 with 32 bytes of data:
No resources.
No resources.
No resources.
No resources.

Ping statistics for 8.8.8.8:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 0, Lost = 4 (100% loss),

C:\Users\user>
```

I have no idea what 'resources' it is referring to or where to look.
It seems the only way to resolve this is to reboot, which is not satisfactory and should not be necessary.
I should be able to shutdown just my WiFi/Ethernet interface then restart it.

Can anyone please tell me what is going on?
What exactly these 'resources' to which it is referring?

Comment: I found this post: https://www.peppercrew.nl/index.php/2019/02/after-disconnecting-vpn-no-network-connection-and-ping-returns-no-resources/

This appears to identify the exact problem and give a fix, but I doesn't really answer the question: "what resources does this error refer to?"

Answer (score 1):

It refers to some kind of file descriptors/ sockets which are created and used for outbound connection. Maybe windows is unable to do that due to a bad NIC. I would recommend updating the NIC drivers. If you face this issue again, run `ipconfig /renew` and please update if ping starts working.

Comment: PING started working after a few minutes or after a reboot. I suspect there is an issue with Windows dealing with changing the network stack when I connect or disconnect from a VPN. Could also be a bug in the WAN Miniport drivers?